# pass input data from one component to another component in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to learning `React`.
I wanted to make it: when entering data into the `input`, this data automatically appear in `H1`in another component.

**Screen.js**

```
    class Screen extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="screen">
          <h1>Text from input</h1>
        </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Screen;
```

**Inputs.js**

```
class Inputs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Value: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default Inputs;
```

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <Inputs />
      <Screen />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As your component is diffrenet and you are not importing in Inputs component so you have to use redux for that.

Comment: You could move the state up to the parent (`App`) component or use a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to access the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to lift the state up to the `app.js`.

```
export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <Inputs val={val} setVal={setVal} />
      <Screen val={val}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your `inputs.js`

```
export default const Inputs({val, setVal}) => {
  const handleChange => (event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  };

  const handleSubmit => (event) {
    alert('Value: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" value={val} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default Inputs;
```

Your `screen.js`

````
export default const Screen({val}) => {

        return (
          <div className="screen">
          <h1>{val}</h1>
        </div>
        );
      }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

write your app.js code as

```
export default function App() {
```

const [input,setInput] = useState('')
const  setInputValue = (value) => {
setInput(value)
}
return (

## {`Hello StackBlitz!${input}`}

Start editing to see some magic happen :)

);
}

and inside  your handleChange function write props.setInputValue(event.target.value)

and use input props in Screen.js file as props.input

Comment: I did as you said and now I have another problem
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')